# proving/disproving the statements

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to, if possible , to receive assistance, in layman terms, in the proving/disproving of the following statements:

$ 1)$ If the positive series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n} $ converges, then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n+1} $ converges as well.

$ 2)$ If  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n} $ converges, and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n} $ converges absolutely, then  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}b_{n} $  converges .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1):

> You can define $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k a_k$.
>
> It is clear that $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges. Now:
>
> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{n} k a_{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{k+1}(s_{k+1} - s_k)
> = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{k-1}{k} s_k - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{k+1} s_k
> =\\ \frac{n}{n+1} s_{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}s_k.$$
>
> It follows that the last expression converges as $n\to\infty$.

For 2):

> Convergent implies bounded.
>
> If $a_n\le c$ then $\sum a_nb_n\le \sum cb_n\le c\sum b_n$, and the latter converges.